# Hangfire - Manually force polling?

Tags: hangfire

Right after enqueuing a job, is there some way to send a message the polling engine, so if it is idle waiting for poll delay, it would 'wake-up' and poll next jobs right away ?

Comment: In my opinion it is not possible. Hangfire doesn't expose any web api by default. You could reduce the polling interval instead.

Comment: Don't need a web api, direct call using hangfire dll's api would be fine

Comment: No, it's not possible. Hangfire worker is a separate process polling data from db. You can interact with it only via db. Even when you're triggering a task in dashboard, you're actually just writing a db record.